# Files being transfered to Public IP

Tags: ssh, ip

I have a bit of an issue. Every night my Ubuntu server is sending data to an external IP:

[image: Firewall logs]

How can I see what is being transferred and how do I stop it?

Comment: You'd need to use packet capturing software, such as `tshark` or `tcpdump`. There's GUI version, Wireshark, but if it's a server and you don't have GUI installed there ( which you should not have anyway on a server) - then `tshark` is better

Comment: You might also want to check the output of the `netstat` command while the transfer happens. It could tell you which process on your machine is involved in the transfer.